# Variable CSS based on browser and Wordpress cache

Tags: html, css, wordpress

for a header.php file of Wordpress blog, I need to add an item on CSS only if browser is Firefox (Gecko).
I've made a php script and all works fine, but if I enable cache plugin, this save the static page that the first browser is showing.

So I tried to use dinamic CSS, but it has no effect. Here is the code that I've on header.php:

`<!--[if Gecko ]> <div class="class" id="section-header" style="background-image:url('background.png'); background-repeat:repeat-x; margin-top:-50px;">  <![endif]-->`

`<div class="class" id="section-header" style="background-image:url('background.png'); background-repeat:repeat-x">`

So, if the browser is Gecko based, add margin-top:-50px, else do nothing.

Why this code doesn't work?

Thanks

Comment: Aren't those `<!--[if ... ]>` type things specific to Internet Explorer only? So they'd never work in Firefox anyway; it'll just treat it as a comment block : `<!-- ..... -->`

Comment: I think you're confusing dynamic CSS and HTML-based conditions (which only work with IE). If you want to use dynamic elements and CSS, you needs to use PHP. See [wp_check_browser_version](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_check_browser_version)

Comment: conditional comments `<!--[if ..]>` only work in IE, i believe there are third party libraries that work with other browsers such as [Conditional-CSS](http://www.conditional-css.com/) but i have never used them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just go ahead and add the class name to identify the element and use conditional CSS to target FF:

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
    div.class {
        margin-top:-50px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Modernizr to detect browser type

```
if($.browser.chrome) {
   $( "body" ).addClass( "chrome" );
} else if ($.browser.mozilla) {
   $( "body" ).addClass( "mozilla" );
} else if ($.browser.msie) {
   $( "body" ).addClass( "msie" );
}
```

Comment: Thanks anyway, I prefer to use the above solution